# Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match while doing masking

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting this error while masking.
Code:

```
ratings.head()
userid  isbn    rating
276725  034545104X  0
276726  0155061224  5
276727  0446520802  0
276729  052165615X  3
276729  0521795028  6
```

when i write

```
ratings['userid'].value_counts()>300
```

i am getting

```
11676      True
198711     True
153662     True
98391      True
35859      True
          ...  
116180    False
116166    False
116154    False
116137    False
276723    False
```

but i did masking i am geting an error

```
ratings[ratings['userid'].value_counts()>300]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always fix your code with `reindex`

```
ratings[(ratings['userid'].value_counts().reindex(ratings['userid'])>300).values]
```

Or `isin`

```
s = ratings['userid'].value_counts()

out = ratings[ratings['userid'].isin(s.index[s>300])]
```